# Avoid cycles to list paths of given length in a graph in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I have the following graph

[image]

I try to model the above graph in Neo4j such that for any duplicate node (say A), a property 'count' on the node is incremented to reflect the number of occurrences of A. Similarly, for any duplicate relationship (say A->B), a property 'frequency' is updated.

A Neo4j console for the graph is implemented [here](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=nycleg).

I modeled the graph in the above way keeping in mind that I could track the number of occurrences of each node and each individual transitions.

The next part of my requirement is to track all 3-nodes path and this is the query I issue, the output of which is visible in the Neo4j console -

```
MATCH (n)-[]->(m)-[]->(p) return n.name+' - '+m.name+' - '+p.name as NewName
```

However, the output I would like to have is -

```
A - B - C
B - D - A
D - A - B
B - D - E
E - B - C
D - E - B
A - B - D
```

But since the nodes and relationship are unique, one additional combination is also reported.

```
E - B - D
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. What would I need to change in the graph setup/query so as to report only the 7 listed combinations instead of the 8 combinations?
2. Is there a way to also count the frequency of such 3-nodes path?

I am fine creating multiple CYPHER scripts to achieve this. That being said, the CYPHER scripts are auto - generated as part of a bigger workflow and I would like to avoid manually typing the n-nodes path(s) and its frequency.

Comment: Very good question - I am not sure you can solve it using plain Cypher (not to mention having reasonable performance). Can you use Neo4j procedures (apoc)?

Comment: A - B - D is a valid 3-node combination, so there are actually 7 valid combinations.

Comment: @cybersam: You are right. A - B - D is also a valid combination. I have edited the question to reflect that as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your data model. You do not need to calculate and update `count` and `frequency` properties; instead, they can be obtained directly from the appropriate data model.

For example, let's use an alternate data model to create your sample data. Every named node is represented once as a `Foo` node. Every usage of a `Foo` node is represented by a `Bar` node that references its `Foo` node via a `FOR` relationship. `Bar` nodes are linked together via `NEXT` relationships.

#### Create sample data

```
CREATE (a:Foo {name: 'A'}), (b:Foo {name: 'B'}), (c:Foo {name: 'C'}), (d:Foo {name: 'D'}), (e:Foo {name: 'E'})
CREATE (a1:Bar)-[:FOR]->(a), (b1:Bar)-[:FOR]->(b),
  (a1)-[:NEXT]->(b1)
CREATE (c1:Bar)-[:FOR]->(c),
  (b1)-[:NEXT]->(c1)
CREATE (d1:Bar)-[:FOR]->(d),
  (b1)-[:NEXT]->(d1)
CREATE (a2:Bar)-[:FOR]->(a),
  (d1)-[:NEXT]->(a2)
CREATE (b2:Bar)-[:FOR]->(b),
  (a2)-[:NEXT]->(b2)
CREATE (e1:Bar)-[:FOR]->(e),
  (d1)-[:NEXT]->(e1)
CREATE (b3:Bar)-[:FOR]->(b),
  (e1)-[:NEXT]->(b3)
CREATE (c2:Bar)-[:FOR]->(c),
  (b3)-[:NEXT]->(c2);
```

#### Get the number of times each Foo node is used:

```
MATCH (f:Foo)<--() RETURN f, COUNT(*) AS count;
```

#### Get the number of times each pair of Foo nodes are used in sequence:

```
MATCH (f1:Foo)<-[:FOR]-()-[:NEXT]->()-[:FOR]->(f2:Foo)
RETURN f1, f2, COUNT(*) AS count;
```

#### Get the number of times each triplet of Foo nodes are used in sequence:

```
MATCH (f1:Foo)<-[:FOR]-()-[:NEXT]->(b1)-[:FOR]->(f2:Foo), (b1)-[:NEXT]->(b2)-[:FOR]->(f3:Foo)
RETURN f1, f2, f3, COUNT(*) as count;
```

Here is the result of the last query, which shows all 7 valid triplets and the number of times they occured:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| f1                | f2                | f3                | count    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[3]{name:"D"} | Node[4]{name:"E"} | Node[1]{name:"B"} | 1        |
| Node[1]{name:"B"} | Node[3]{name:"D"} | Node[4]{name:"E"} | 1        |
| Node[4]{name:"E"} | Node[1]{name:"B"} | Node[2]{name:"C"} | 1        |
| Node[3]{name:"D"} | Node[0]{name:"A"} | Node[1]{name:"B"} | 1        |
| Node[1]{name:"B"} | Node[3]{name:"D"} | Node[0]{name:"A"} | 1        |
| Node[0]{name:"A"} | Node[1]{name:"B"} | Node[3]{name:"D"} | 1        |
| Node[0]{name:"A"} | Node[1]{name:"B"} | Node[2]{name:"C"} | 1        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This was wonderful. I am using your solution as a reference to check if the same logic can be extended to find all quadruplets of Foo nodes. It should definitely be possible.

Comment: Quadruplets or any for that matter is perfectly possible with your data model. In my case, all such cypher queries comes in separate files which may have the nodes with same names. The logic is applicable to this case as well, with minor modifications on the queries. Can you help me understand if its the correct way to do it - http://console.neo4j.org/?id=l6hzof